# Where do roboticists look for used sensors/hardware?

Tags: sensors, otherservos

I recently built a self-driving vehicle-type robot for a competition, and am looking to sell sensors (GPS, INS, etc.) used in order to have money for the next project. Is ebay where people tend to go looking for used sensors and hardware?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Alejandro Carrillo, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use ebay for selling and buying individual used sensors or other bits. I've also used gumtree when I had stuff to clear but wasn't looking for money for it. Ebay has quite detailed search/categorising which I think makes it more appropriate for technology stuff.